# Sed or awk extract phone number in whole file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'am working on parsing SMS numbers from email messages and I got one problem. I'am using awk and sed in bash script. The format of phone number is `SMS: +XXX XXX XXX XXX` . When there is this string included in email body i need to send SMS with subject. All working well so far but I got an issue when there is this string multiple on one line or after some web link. Currently I'am using this to parse phone numbers into array and then create files with number in name.

```
phone=( $( awk /SMS/ $FILE | awk '{ gsub (" ", "", $0); print}' ) )
```

Works fine when there is SMS string on separate lines. I need same to parse string when there is more strings on one line: 
`SMS: +123 456 789 123   SMS: +456 789 123 456`
or
`http://somelink/to/some/web/page.html SMS: +123 456 789 123`
Basically it would be best to parse whole file and find anything after `SMS:` which is in format `+XXX XXX XXX XXX` . Also it is not sure that after last digit will be line break - so it might be between 2 separate strings. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: You can pipe your input through `sed 's/SMS/\nSMS/g'` just as a pre-step.  Then everything in the input starting with `SMS` will start on a new line.  Probably solves your issues.

Comment: Read up on the basics of awk. The fact that you are piping shows you have not even read basic commands for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep -o` will make your life easier:

```
grep -oE 'SMS: \+([[:digit:]]{3} ?){4}' "$file"
```

That will spit out each match on a separate line, no matter how many occur on the same line in the input.

Also, get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES. One day you'll accidentally use `PATH=...` and then wonder why your script is broken.

Comment: I would use `grep -o '^SMS \+[0-9 ]*[0-9]'` instead, just to allow also (to me seemingly) valid numbers like `SMS +49 152 30423423`, but that's up to the precise spec PO has to code against.

Comment: @Alfe It doesn't return anything. Test on file with exported email body - multiple lines with SMS: and number.

Comment: @marty, remove the leading `^` from Alfe's regex.

Comment: Of course, yes.  That `^` inly made sense with my former idea of breaking the lines at each `SMS` occurrence.  My apologies.

Comment: @Alfe @glenn jackman - I've test it and still doesn't work. Using this `grep -o 'SMS \+[0-9 ]*[0-9]' `  and piping contetn to this with cat from file, but it should not be a problem. - Solved - missing colon - this works `grep -oE 'SMS: \+[0-9 ]*[0-9]'`